# Three.js TypeError: lastQuaternion.dot is not a function

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm new to Three.js and javascript in general. I'm currently trying to display a model in the browser. It's working OK, except when I open my console with Firebug, I have this error that states:

```
TypeError: lastQuaternion.dot is not a function

|| 8 * (1 - lastQuaternion.dot(this.object.quaternion)) > EPS ) { ...OrbitControls.js(line 293)
```

The .dot attribute seems to belong to Vector3.js in the src. I have linked in OrbitControls.js into my index.html to be able to move around the model, which is working, however this unsettling error keeps counting up infinitely every millisecond or so...

Does anyone know what the cause of this may be? Or has anyone encountered a similar error?

Thanks.

Comment: Good, you should add that as an answer and accept it as such when you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just discovered the answer. I was using a mix of different versions of three.js because I was following a few different tutorials online. (One version for OrbitControls.js and a different one for Three.js) 
Credit goes to this question: [Error in Trackball controls.update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397718/error-in-trackball-controls-update). 
Also, the unsettling error was counting up infinitely because `controls.update();`, controls being the variable for `new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);` was in a render loop.